# Map char * in C DLL to Java with JNA

Tags: java, visual-c++, jna

I have a DLL of C++ and I need to call its function which returns `char*`. Im using String in native declaration but getting output like `????` or some crap thing. Do I have to decode the String? I have already set my system property like this:

```
 System.setProperty("jna.encoding","UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import com.sun.jna.*;
```

**char* Return from C method:**

```
Pointer myFunc();
Pointer ptr = myFunc();
String str = ptr.getString(0);
str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf(0));  //Remove garbage after null char
```

**char* Param to pass into C method:**

```
void myFunc(Pointer ptr);
String str = "hello world";
Memory mem = new Memory(str.length());
mem.write(0, str.getBytes(), 0, str.length());
myFunc(mem);
```

Answer (score 0):

jna.encoding will have no effect if the original string is unicode.  You need to use com.sun.jna.WString instead, or see the example W32API mappings for how to automatically map unicode (wchar_t*) strings to String.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use `Native.toString()` to convert the string back to Java?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Pointer instead of String and then use the getString(long offset) method of pointer to get the string, it implicitly uses the jna.encoding if set.